# Java database quiz with score counter

Tags: java, mysql

I have been trying to increment a count every time the right answer is clicked on a quiz I have made, I understand that the problem is that the if statement that counts the score takes place at the end of the button's action event, so it will count for the next answer, not the current one.

I thought this would be easy to fix and I could just move the if statement above where I am shuffling answers(see below) however this does not work in any location, the program will instead return the exception when a correct answer is encountered. If anyone could help me that would be cool.

I also realize I might be being a bit vague here, but I can try to explain anything that doesn't make sense.

```
private void answerBtn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:   
       try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbcTest?user=test&password=hihi";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            java.sql.Statement st = (java.sql.Statement) conn.createStatement();
            String find = "select quest,answer,wrongAns,wrongAns2,wrongAns3,q_sel from Question where country = 'ireland' and q_sel = 'N' order by rand() limit 1;"; 
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(find);

            /* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY4FavUyFNQ */ 

            while(rs.next()){
              question = questionLbl.getText();
              questionLbl.setText("\n"+rs.getString("quest")); 
              java.sql.Statement st2 = conn.createStatement();
              st2.executeUpdate("update Question set q_sel = 'Y' where quest = '"+rs.getString("quest")+"'");

              String[] solutionArray = {rs.getString("answer"),rs.getString("wrongAns"),rs.getString("wrongAns2"),rs.getString("wrongAns3")};

              arr = solutionArray;
              count2++;

              Random rgen = new Random();
              int N = arr.length;

            /*
            * fisher yates shuffle
            *
            * 9/3/2015
            *
            * @reference http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/Knuth.java.html
            * @author sean trant 13332576
            */ 

              for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                // choose index uniformly in [i, N-1]
                int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (N - i));

                Object swap = arr[r];
                arr[r] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = (String)swap;

                answerBtn1.setText(arr[0]);
                answerBtn2.setText(arr[1]);
                answerBtn3.setText(arr[2]);
                answerBtn4.setText(arr[3]); 
            }

             if(arr[0].equals(rs.getString("answer"))){
                count++;
                scoreLbl.setText("Score:"+count);
                }     
            }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error"); 
            }

    }
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Your loops aren't indented.

Comment: Where do you store the answer to the current question? It seems like this code is mostly dealing with the next question.

Comment: the answers are stored in a database, with this code I am retrieving 1 question and its relative answers every time the button is clicked